# Sql Server Data Types

Tags: sql, sql-server, types, datetimeoffset

I am writing a script that will generate a column of every data type within sql server. I know that sql-server considers things like decimal(5,1) and decimal(5,0) as different data types, however the various resources that I have looked at (w3schools and the microsoft reference page) do not make it clear if this is also the case for things like: Binary (length), or datetimeoffset(0-7), etc. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the answer is a bit messy.

On the one hand the [SQL Server datatypes page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx) clearly makes a distinction between "data types, collations, precision, scale, or length".

So that would indicate that collations, precision, scale, or length are all attributes distinct from datatype.

However the same page also mentions

> Large value data types: varchar(max), nvarchar(max), and varbinary(max)

So that would imply that adding the `max` does change the datatype in some sense. Then also you've got cases like `float(24)` which is treated in SQL Server as a distinct datatype of `real`.

What is the purpose of this script? Simply generating a column of every data type doesn't sound useful in its own. What is it for? What makes sense for the script?

Comment: From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx, "For the decimal and numeric data types, SQL Server considers each specific combination of precision and scale as a different data type".  Exactly what is considered a different data type I guess depends on the context (e.g. physical storage, semantics).

Answer (score 1):

if  you are interested with only every data type within sql server, you can get these information from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
you can run this script:

```
use my_databas
go

SELECT distinct  
    DATA_TYPE , 
    CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,    
    CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH,     
    NUMERIC_PRECISION , NUMERIC_SCALE
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

order by 1,2,3

**Edit:**

The table **sys.types** Contains a row for each system and user-defined type.

The next query get all data types in the sql server

```
select *
from sys.types
order by name
```

For decimal /binary data types , the storage is based on the following table:

```
Precision   Storage bytes
    1 - 9   5
    10-19   9
    20-28   13
    29-38   17
```

reference: [decimal and numeric](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx)

Precision is the maximum total number of decimal digits that will be stored, both to the left and to the right of the decimal point.

for example 
decimal(5,1) (Precision 6) and decimal(5,0) (Precision  5)  have the same storage 5 bytes each

Comment: This will return only data types of existing columns, not every possible data type within SQL Server as what I understand to be the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where did that information come from.

SQL Server specifies decimal(x,y) a data type - an exact numeric data type. The difference is amount of bytes it uses, and that makes it "consider" numeric(5,1) and numeric(5,0) as different data types. Key difference is when operation on two numerics is required (addition or any other), SQL Server tries to adapt to the precision that should account for the correct result.

Almost the same thing should happen with binary(x). When operation is performed between different precisions, you should get the precision that should contain the correct result.

Datetimeoffset(0-7) should follow the same logic.